# Building a Basic WordPress Page

Tags: wordpress

I know that WordPress pages get built from

1. a .php template
2. a style.css file
3. any content in the post_content column of the wp_posts table.

But is 3 really necessary?  Suppose you wanted to build a page that just had an input form that collected data and stored it in a custom table of the database. Couldn't you do the whole thing in a custom template and a style sheet?  Or what if you wanted to build a page that just read information from this custom database table and displayed in in an HTML table?

Thanks

Comment: You seem to answer your own question. WordPress templates can do anything. They're not limited to interacting with the WP database.

Comment: Yes, but my point is they seem to be able to do useful stuff without pulling any content from wp_posts.  And then you don't even need a loop in the template.